# Has anyone been able to setup create react app with semantic-ui?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, create-react-app

If so, please share folder structure (where is semantic path) and an example of importing a component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will make use of the react package https://react.semantic-ui.com/ . Same stuff but without jquery and all react components

Comment: I'm able to install it - but the dist folder never builds, and create-react-app doesn't support less.

Comment: Ok but did you try the semantic-react library ? Gonna be easier + all the components is on react and not jquery. http://hallister.github.io/semantic-react/

Comment: i did and also stardust, which is the official semantic - react implementation. but the scope of this question is for the main semantic-ui lib, not offshoot or fork.

Comment: this is why i never go on stack anymore. what reason at all is this being downvoted? pathetic.

Comment: The library you suggested is not the official Semantic react UI the person asking is looking for I believe

Comment: @human I know sorry I edit, at the time I wrote this that was the only version available.

Answer (score 37):

I know this question is rather "old" (in a front-end dev sense), but Semantic UI now has official React integration and bindings:

## Semantic UI React

https://react.semantic-ui.com/

Among its key features (from the landing page):

**jQuery Free**

All jQuery functionality has been re-implemented in React.

**Declarative API**

Declarative APIs provide for robust features and prop validation.

**Augmentation**

Control the rendered HTML tag, or render one component as another component. Extra props are passed to the component you are rending as.

**Shorthand Props**

Shorthand props generate markup for you, making many use cases a breeze. All object props are spread on the child components.

**Sub Components**

Sub components give you complete access to the markup. This is essential for flexibility in customizing components.

**Auto Controlled State**

Our stateful components self manage their state out of the box, without wiring. Dropdowns open on click without wiring onClick to the open prop. The value is also stored internally, without wiring onChange to value.

### Installation

```
$ npm install semantic-ui-react --save
$ npm install semantic-ui-css --save
```

or if you prefer Yarn:

```
$ yarn add semantic-ui-react
$ yarn add semantic-ui-css
```

After installing, include this line in your `index.js` file:

```
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
```

Comment: I'm surprised this information isn't  stated as clearly as you have anywhere in the semantic-ui-react docs

Comment: I suppose I could add it to their docs, though it's somewhat c-r-a specific. But that hasn't stopped other projects. I'll take a stab at it when some free time opens up.

Comment: These instructions are in the official docs now, and are c-r-a compatible:
https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage